# Memory requirements for FFT

Tags: fft

I have a system with limited memory. So basically the question is this: If I have (say) 24KB of data space and 4096 data samples of single precision floats (16KB) can I do an FFT on the data? More generally, what is the minimum data space required to do an FFT?

Comment: This strongly depends on the implementation, of course. Are you planning to use a specific library?

Comment: Probably the CMSIS DSP_Lib on a Cortex M4 core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation of the CMSIS-DSP FFT function](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group___complex_f_f_t.html):

> The FFT functions operate in-place. That is, the array holding the
>   input data will also be used to hold the corresponding result. The
>   input data is complex and contains 2*fftLen interleaved values as
>   shown below.

It is possible to implement the FFT in such a way, that it does not require additional buffers but uses the memory of the input array for its output. This method is usually referred to as "in-place" calculation. From the above citation I think that the CMSIS-DSP library does exactly that (though we can not know for sure without the source code).

So in this case, yes, a memory size of 16 KB is sufficient.

That an in-place calculation is possible can be understood from the butterfly diagram, see for example [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/FFT_Butterfly_radix8.svg/420px-FFT_Butterfly_radix8.svg.png).